# Iterative multiplication of relative transforms leads to fast instability

Tags: c++11, eigen3

I'm writing a program that receives Eigen transforms and stores them in a container after applying some noise. In particular, at time k, I receive transform T<sub>k</sub>. I get from the container the transform T<sub>k-1</sub>, create the delta = T<sub>k-1</sub><sup>-1</sup> · T<sub>k</sub>, apply some noise to delta and store T<sub>k-1</sub> · delta as a new element of the container.

I've noticed that after 50 iterations the values are completely wrong and at every iteration I see that the last element of the container, when pre-multiplied by its inverse, is not even equal to the identity.

I've already checked that the container follows the rules of allocation specified by Eigen. 
I think the problem is related to the instability of the operations I'm doing.

The following simple code produce the  nonzero values when `max = 35` and goes to infinity when `max` is bigger than 60.

```
Eigen::Isometry3d my_pose = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
my_pose.translate(Eigen::Vector3d::Random());
my_pose.rotate(Eigen::Quaterniond::UnitRandom());
Eigen::Isometry3d my_other_pose = my_pose;
int max = 35;
for(int i=0; i < max; i++)
{
    my_pose = my_pose * my_pose.inverse() * my_pose;
}
std::cerr << my_pose.matrix() - my_other_pose.matrix() << std::endl;
```

I'm surprised how fast the divergence happens. Since my real program is expected to iterate more than hundreds of times, is there a way to create relative transforms that are more stable?

Comment: Small hint: You might be luckier in finding an answer at [SciComp Stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a `Quaterniond` for the rotations:

```
Eigen::Isometry3d my_pose = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
my_pose.translate(Eigen::Vector3d::Random());
my_pose.rotate(Eigen::Quaterniond::UnitRandom());
Eigen::Isometry3d my_other_pose = my_pose;
Eigen::Quaterniond q(my_pose.rotation());
int max = 35;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    std::cerr << q.matrix() << "\n\n";
    std::cerr << my_pose.matrix() << "\n\n";
    q = q * q.inverse() * q;
    my_pose = my_pose * my_pose.inverse() * my_pose;
}
std::cerr << q.matrix() - Eigen::Quaterniond(my_other_pose.rotation()).matrix() << "\n";
std::cerr << my_pose.matrix() - my_other_pose.matrix() << std::endl;
```

If you would have examined the difference you printed out, the rotation part of the matrix gets a huge error, while the translation part is tolerable. The inverse on the rotation matrix will hit stability issues quickly, so using it directly is usually not recommended.

Comment: Why isn't the class `Isometry3d` not using the `Quaterniond` internally? Isn't there a way to tell it to use quaternions internally and output the rototation matrix on-the-fly when I call `.matrix()`?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176533/how-to-ensure-eigen-isometry-stays-isometric).

Comment: @MarcoCamurri Using Quaternions instead of matrices is inferior when applying the transformation to (multiple) vectors. Quaternions are beneficial when multiplying rotations and are much easier to (re-) normalize. If you want both, you will always have to compromise.

Comment: @MarcoCamurri, by “inferior” chtz means “less efficient,” not “less accurate.”